# FreeRadius & PI - Constant failure

Tags: raspberry-pi4, freeradius

I'm new to Freeradius. Relatively familiar with linux. I've never been this stumped by an issue like this before.

No matter what I do, or how I config freeradius on my Pi, I end up with the following error when trying to start the service. This error will just repeat.

I've played with permissions & wiped the pi twice, followed many tutorials, and I still hit the same spot.

Can anyone help please?

```
lines 2500-2551/2551 (END)
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://www.debian.org/support
░░ 
░░ A start job for unit freeradius.service has begun execution.
░░ 
░░ The job identifier is 13806.
Mar 04 19:44:11 raspberrypi freeradius[4362]: FreeRADIUS Version 3.0.21
Mar 04 19:44:11 raspberrypi freeradius[4362]: Copyright (C) 1999-2019 The FreeRADIUS server project and contributors
Mar 04 19:44:11 raspberrypi freeradius[4362]: There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
Mar 04 19:44:11 raspberrypi freeradius[4362]: PARTICULAR PURPOSE
Mar 04 19:44:11 raspberrypi freeradius[4362]: You may redistribute copies of FreeRADIUS under the terms of the
Mar 04 19:44:11 raspberrypi freeradius[4362]: GNU General Public License
Mar 04 19:44:11 raspberrypi freeradius[4362]: For more information about these matters, see the file named COPYRIGHT
Mar 04 19:44:11 raspberrypi freeradius[4362]: Starting - reading configuration files ...
Mar 04 19:44:11 raspberrypi freeradius[4362]: Debug state unknown (cap_sys_ptrace capability not set)
Mar 04 19:44:11 raspberrypi freeradius[4362]: Creating attribute Unix-Group
Mar 04 19:44:11 raspberrypi freeradius[4362]: Creating attribute LDAP-Group
Mar 04 19:44:11 raspberrypi freeradius[4362]: Please use tls_min_version and tls_max_version instead of disable_tlsv1
Mar 04 19:44:11 raspberrypi freeradius[4362]: Please use tls_min_version and tls_max_version instead of disable_tlsv1_2
Mar 04 19:44:11 raspberrypi freeradius[4362]: tls: Using cached TLS configuration from previous invocation
Mar 04 19:44:11 raspberrypi freeradius[4362]: tls: Using cached TLS configuration from previous invocation
Mar 04 19:44:11 raspberrypi freeradius[4362]: rlm_cache (cache_eap): Driver rlm_cache_rbtree (module rlm_cache_rbtree) loaded and linked
Mar 04 19:44:11 raspberrypi freeradius[4362]: rlm_detail (auth_log): 'User-Password' suppressed, will not appear in detail output
Mar 04 19:44:11 raspberrypi freeradius[4362]: rlm_ldap: libldap vendor: OpenLDAP, version: 20457
Mar 04 19:44:11 raspberrypi freeradius[4362]: rlm_ldap (ldap): Initialising connection pool
Mar 04 19:44:11 raspberrypi freeradius[4362]: rlm_mschap (mschap): using internal authentication
Mar 04 19:44:11 raspberrypi freeradius[4362]: Ignoring "sql" (see raddb/mods-available/README.rst)
Mar 04 19:44:11 raspberrypi freeradius[4362]:  # Skipping contents of 'if' as it is always 'false' -- /etc/freeradius/3.0/sites-enabled/inner-tunnel:>
Mar 04 19:44:11 raspberrypi freeradius[4362]: radiusd: #### Skipping IP addresses and Ports ####
Mar 04 19:44:11 raspberrypi freeradius[4362]: Configuration appears to be OK
Mar 04 19:44:11 raspberrypi systemd[1]: freeradius.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
░░ Subject: Unit process exited
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://www.debian.org/support
░░ 
░░ An ExecStart= process belonging to unit freeradius.service has exited.
░░ 
░░ The process' exit code is 'exited' and its exit status is 1.
Mar 04 19:44:11 raspberrypi systemd[1]: freeradius.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
░░ Subject: Unit failed
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://www.debian.org/support
░░ 
░░ The unit freeradius.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'.
Mar 04 19:44:11 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Failed to start FreeRADIUS multi-protocol policy server.
░░ Subject: A start job for unit freeradius.service has failed
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://www.debian.org/support
░░ 
░░ A start job for unit freeradius.service has finished with a failure.
░░ 
░░ The job identifier is 13806 and the job result is failed.
```

Comment: I had to laugh, "Failed with result"... 'exit-code' – almost helpful!

Comment: You might see more debug info if you run freeradius from the command line with the `-X` option for full debugging.

Answer (score -1):

I actually found the answer. There was a typo in Googles instructions. It's minor and I missed it:

https://support.google.com/a/answer/9089736?hl=en#zippy=%2Cfreeradius

It uses both .cer and .crt for the same certificate file as shown below.

Follow these steps:

1. Install and configure FreeRADIUS at `/etc/freeradius/3.0/`.

   Once FreeRADIUS is installed, you can add the LDAP configuration by installing the freeradius-ldap plugin.

   ```
   sudo apt install freeradius freeradius-ldap
   ```
2. Copy the LDAP client key and cert files to `/etc/freeradius/3.0/certs/ldap-client.key` and `/etc/freeradius/3.0/certs/ldap-client.crt` respectively.

   ```
   chown freeradius:freeradius /etc/freeradius/3.0/certs/ldap-client.*
   chmod 640 /etc/freeradius/3.0/certs/ldap-client.*
   ```
3. Enable the LDAP module.

   ```
   cd /etc/freeradius/3.0/mods-enabled/
   ln -s ../mods-available/ldap ldap
   ```
4. Edit `/etc/freeradius/3.0/mods-available/ldap`.

   a. ldap->server = 'ldaps://ldap.google.com:636'
   b. identity = username from the application credentials
   c. password = password from the application credentials
   d. base_dn = 'dc=domain,dc=com'
   e. tls->start_tls = no
   f. tls->certificate_file = /etc/freeradius/3.0/certs/ldap-client.cer
   g. tls->private_key_file = /etc/freeradius/3.0/certs/ldap-client.key
   h. tls->require_cert = 'allow'
   i. Comment out all fields in the breadcrumb representing the section 'ldap -> post-auth -> update'
5. ​Edit `/etc/freeradius/3.0/sites-available/default`.

   This modifies the FreeRadius client connection. If you are not using the default client, be sure to update the relevant client (inner-tunnel or any custom client) that you have configured.

   a. Modify the authorize section to add the following block at the bottom after the password authentication protocol (PAP) statement:

   ```
   if (User-Password) {
       update control {
           Auth-Type := ldap
       }
   }
   ```

   b. In the authorize section, enable LDAP by removing the '-' sign before it.

   ```
   #
   #  The ldap module reads passwords from the LDAP database.
   ldap
   ```

   c. Modify the authenticate section by editing the Auth-Type LDAP block as follows:

   ```
    # Auth-Type LDAP {
        ldap
    # }
   ```

   d. Modify the authenticate section by editing the Auth-Type PAP block as follows:

   ```
   Auth-Type PAP {
       #  pap
       ldap
   }
   ```

Comment: Please add all clarification to your answer by editing it. Don't just post links to external ressources